# Recycler view not visible when i add scrollview as a parent of Linear layout where Recycler view is placed with frame layout and swipe refresh layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, swiperefreshlayout

Recyler view items are not displayed when i placed parent of the same inside scrollview or nested scrollview.
My requirement is to add scrollview to half of the screen which includes recyclerview with frame layout and swipe refresh layout.

I have tried scrollview and nestedscrollview but its not coming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_cusine_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/food_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_white"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_cusine_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/white_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_name"
            android:layout_width="183dp"

            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/arrow_white"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_cusine_1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/arrow_white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrow_white"
            android:text="Restaurant Name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_name_sub"
                style="@style/RestuarantNames"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Restuarant Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_ratings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/textGreen"
                android:text="3.6"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                style="@style/UserLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/detail_retaurant_list_ratings_header" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rating" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                style="@style/UserLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/detail_retaurant_list_delivery_place_header" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/green_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:contentDescription="User Location"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_user_location"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="146dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                    android:text="Rajouri Garden"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <!--<TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/user_address_change"
                    android:text="@string/user_change"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    style="@style/User_Green_Font" />-->
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Delivery in 33 minutes.Live tracking available"
                android:textColor="#FF7F50"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/vegSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/dish_type_veg"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/HeaderRestuarantsRecommendations"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dish_type_best_sellers" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

                        android:id="@+id/recycler_food_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                <com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
                    app:backgroundTint="#3CB371"
                    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to display image which is inside relativelayout, rest of the contents should be scrollable below image including recylerview contents.
Right now If i put scrollview after relative layout,recyler views contents doesnt show up,without scrollview recyler view lists comes with a scrollbar.

Comment: provide a screen which you want to achieve ?

Comment: Can u try converting from `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. I copy pasted your layout and found that FrameLayout is not working for your scenario. i changed to `RelativeLayout` and it seems to be fine.

Comment: Might be you missed _android:fillViewPort="true"_ for `ScrollView`.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal did you add scrollview after relative because even i add relative layout in place of frame layout and then add scrollview after first relative layout recycler is not showing up.

Comment: @Piyush not working

Comment: I just added the `scrollview` and then the `recyclerview` is not visible. if i comment the `SwipeRefreshLayout` then the `recyclerview` is visible. you can try that as well. Let me try to resolve this issue with `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_cusine_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_white"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_cusine_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_name"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/arrow_white"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_cusine_1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/arrow_white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/arrow_white"
        android:text="Restaurant Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_wienter code heredth="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_name_sub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Restuarant Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detail_restaurant_ratings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="3.6"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="String text" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="detail_retaurant_list_delivery_place_header" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/green_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:contentDescription="User Location"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="146dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
                    android:text="Rajouri Garden"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Delivery in 33 minutes.Live tracking available"
                android:textColor="#FF7F50"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/vegSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="dish_type_veg"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="string/dish_type_best_sellers" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_food_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    app:backgroundTint="#3CB371"
                    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I guess this will work. I changed the `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and then added *android:fillViewport="true"* to `Nestedscrollview`. Now the `recyclerview` seems to be visible. You can try the same and let me know if it works

Comment: This solution worked for me,i can see recycler view items but cannot scroll under the image,ie nested scrollview is not visibile,any thoughts here?

Comment: You will have to add 'recyclerview.setnestedscrollingenabled(false)' and also try adding recyclerview.sethasfixedsize(true)

Comment: Can you help me to understand what i was doing wrong with frame layout and scrollview?

Comment: added this  'recyclerview.setnestedscrollingenabled(false)' and also try adding recyclerview.sethasfixedsize(true) but it didnt worked for me?